# ServerEventsClient concurrent model in ServiceStack

Tags: events, concurrency, servicestack

I use ServerEventsClient to listen for server events. Also I use JsonServiceClient, which available through the property ServiceClient of the ServerEventsClient class, to send messages to the server. While ServiceClient waits for a response from the server (which may take some time) whether ServerEventsClient to receive events from the server and send heartbeats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [ServerEventsClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServerEventsClient.cs) uses a separate long-lived asynchronous connection to the Server Events `/event-stream` so you can concurrently use the ServiceClient to perform additional requests.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. This applies only to asynchronous requests?

Comment: @VladimirShiyanov no it doesn't block any requests, I'm saying the ServerEventsClient only connects to the SSE /event-stream via a separate long-lived non-blocking async request, it doesn't interfere or block with any ServiceClient request (it doesn't even use the ServiceClient for its SSE event-stream).